# Wordpress, Add Media issue after Theme changed

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, media

i am new to `Wordpress` and `PHP`.

I have an issue with adding images to posts and pages. I can directly upload images to the `Media Library` (`Dashboard/Media`). I think the problem might be my custom theme. When i switch to a different theme the problem goes away.

When i try to add an image to the page it shows this error message: `An error occurred in the upload. Please try again later.`
Also, its not loading the existing images either.

I don't have any plugins installed.
Uploads folder reading and writing permissions is correct.

Any advice or tips that might help, would be appreciated.
A suggestion on how to debug it, would also help. I tried to use chrome developers tool bar, console but didn't find anything.
`Media Library (Dashboard/Media)` upload images is working fine.

Could it be an url issue?
If so where and how can i check my url setting for uploads folder

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you checked with the theme author to see if it is a known issue? Perhaps the theme needs to be updated?

Comment: The theme author is sitting next to me. I will ask. Do you know what type of content in a theme, might affect the uploading of images in add media on pages and blogs? exmaple missing <div> ect. Its just i have no idea where to start looking.

Comment: The Media manager in WordPress is extremely dependent on JavaScript. Any JS conflicts can cause strange behavior. The most common thing I've seen is JS meant for the front end only to get loaded in the Admin and cause issues. Alternatively, it could be JS meant for your theme's administration (if you have that) conflicting. Fastest way to find the conflict is to disable all the `enqueue_script()` calls and see if that fixes it. If not, start commenting out sections of the theme's functions.php file until it works.

Comment: Thanks, sounds like a good approach to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check the size of the file, edit your .htaccess

```
   <IfModule mod_php5.c>
       php_value post_max_size 200M
       php_value upload_max_filesize 200M
       php_value memory_limit 300M
       php_value max_execution_time 259200
       php_value max_input_time 259200
       php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 1200
   </IfModule>
```

or edit your file php.ini

```
    max_execution_time = 180
    max_input_time = 600
    post_max_size = 128M
    upload_max_filesize = 256M
    safe_mode = off
```

PD : Change and test different values

Edit File on Godaddy : https://www.drupal.org/node/1209090 + https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21926795/how-to-create-php-ini-file-in-godaddy

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem. Just in case someone else have the same problem. We had written comments in the HTML sections of the page. Even thought the comments was comment out, it seemed to cause the problem. Hope this will help someone else